# Why does GridSearchCV run longer than programming GridSearch myself?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am interested in using `GridSearchCV` function from `sklearn` on a classification problem using MNIST data. However, the sklearn function takes much more time than a process that, so far as I understand, fits the same number of models. Here is an example (I will take just 2000 observations as training set in order to reduce computation time)

```
# Code chunk 1
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']
x_drop, X_train, y_drop, y_train= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=2000, random_state=42, stratify=y)

C = [1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10]
gamma = [1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2]

params = [(c,g) for c in C for g in gamma]

s = time.time()
for c, g in params:
    svm_rbf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf')
    y_train_pred_poly = cross_val_score(svm_rbf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
print(f' Execution time: {np.round(time.time() - s, 3)} seconds')
```

Execution time: 70.895 seconds

```
# Code chunk 2
svm_rbf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf')

param_grid = [
    {'C':[1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10], 'gamma':[1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2]}
]

s2 = time.time()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(svm_rbf, param_grid, cv=3,
                        scoring='accuracy')

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f' Execution time: {np.round(time.time() - s2, 3)} seconds')
```

Execution time: 171.148 seconds

So far as I understand, in # code chunk 1 I take a list containing 12 elements (the product of 4 values for the hyperparameter C and 3 values for the hyperparameter gamma) and performs 3-fold cross validation. While in chunk code 2 I use the GridSearchCV function to run the same type of algorithm on the same grid of values, using the same number of folds. **But using this function takes 240% more seconds.**

So, what is the difference between these two and why does it take so much longer using `GridSearchCV`?

### EDIT:

Thanks to the comments for pointing out my mistake. The first code chunk is running using always the same parameters, that why it takes less time. The correct code would be:

```
for c, g in params:
    svm_rbf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C=c, gamma=g)
    y_train_pred_poly = cross_val_score(svm_rbf, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
print(f' Execution time: {np.round(time.time() - s, 3)} seconds')
```

Comment: One clear addition to the grid search is the refitting of the winning model on the entire dataset, but that probably doesn't account for such a large increase in time.  Are these being parallelized?  (Try setting `refit=False` in the search, and `n_jobs=1` in both places.)

Comment: There is a bug in your code: in the first chunk you are always using the same parameters: `svm_rbf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf')`. This should be replaced by this one: `svm_rbf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C=c, gamma=g) `. In that case, you will have the same estimators fitted.